# How to prove the bijection from unit interval to unit-square constructed by Cantor is discontinuous?

Tags: set-theory

Can it be proved with mathematical analysis?

Comment: I doubt anyone wants to trawl through Cantor's works to find it, so you'd better tell us what bijection you mean.

Comment: I do not know what bijection you are talking about, but a quick google search gives me [this page](http://plus.maths.org/content/glimpse-cantors-paradise), with the bijection given by taking a point in the unit square and "interweaving" the decimals, for instance $(0.533, 0.123456)\mapsto 0.51323040506$. You can also map the other way by splitting the decimals, with for instance $0.654321\mapsto(0.642, 0.531)$.

Comment: @Arthur That's not a bijection, although it is nearly so. (Non-unique decimal expansions and all that.)

Comment: @MarioCarneiro True, there is some trouble involving trailing nines. But it is the one I found with reference to Cantor and counting the number of points in the plane.

Answer (score 3):

If the bijection were (bi)continuous, then the image of the boundary of the square (homeomorphic to a circle) would be a connected closed subset of the interval.  Such a subset is necessarily an interval itself.  But a circle and an interval have distinct fundamental groups: $\pi_1(I)=0$, while $\pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb Z$.  Since the fundamental group is a homeomorphism invariant, the result follows.

Comment: Why should the preimage of the boundary be connected? It could always map out part of the boundary and then go back later to finish it off. (I'm not saying you're wrong, but there is a bit of a leap to finish the proof by this method.) My favorite proof says that the image of a continuous function from an interval is a nullset in higher dimensions, so it cannot be the whole square.

Comment: Homeomorphisms preserve connectivity in both directions.

Comment: @BabyDragon This may be a stupid question, but isn't there a difference between "continuous" and "homomorphism"? We can't assume the inverse map is continuous, can we?

Comment: This is true. Indeed any map of the form $X_{disc}\to X$ is a continuous bijection where $X_{disc}$ is the discrete topology on the set of points on $X$ and the map is just the identity. But the proof does not seem to say anything about things that are not homeomorphism, unless I am missing something.

Comment: The relevant quote from wiki is "If a continuous bijection has as its domain a compact space and its codomain is Hausdorff, then it is a homeomorphism."  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function (note that the closed interval and square with the usual topology are both compact and Hausdorff).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more elementary argument.  If there were a continuous bijection $f$ from the interval $[0,1]$ to the square, take the points $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ in the square.  They are necessarily distinct since $f$ is a bijection.  Now take two disjoint paths $\alpha$ and $\beta$ from $f(0)$ to $f(1)$ in the square. By the intermediate value theorem, the image of $\alpha$ in $[0,1]$ must be the entire interval $[0,1]$, and similarly for $\beta$.  Therefore $f$ is not bijective.  The contradiction proves the result.

Comment: What do you mean by " the image of $\alpha$ in $[0,1]$ must be the entire interval $[0,1]$"? Isn't the image of $\alpha$ a subset of the square? perhaps you mean the preimage? By the way, this uses the IVT which can be proved with a connectivity argument.

Comment: I am referring to the image of $\alpha$ under the bijection.  In other words, the image of $\alpha$ is a subset of the interval.  The subset is connected, and contains the endpoints. Therefore it has to be the entire interval.

Comment: This is very slick.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is a continuous and bijective function from the unit interval to the unit square it must map compact sets to compact sets. But all closed sets in the unit interval are compact so its maps all closed sets to closed sets. Equivalently it maps open sets to open sets. Thus its inverse $g$ must be continuous as well. Now use any of the other answers ruling out the existence of bicontinuous bijections.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f$ be any continuous bijection from the unit interval to the unit square.
Since, $[0,1]$ is compact $f^{-1}$ will also be a continuous function.

Now consider any point $a$ belonging to $[0,1]$ such that $a$ is an interior point of $[0,1]$ i.e. $a$ belongs to $(0,1)$ then we look at its image $f(a)$. So deleting the point $a$ from $[0,1]$ will give us a disconnected set while its pre-image under $f^{-1}$ i.e. the $unit $ $square$ $-f(a)$ is clearly pathwise connected and hence connected.  (Since, in euclidean spaces pathwise connectedness is equivalent to connectedness).  So, it implies that $f^{-1}$ is a continuous function that maps a connected set to a disconnected set and hence contradiction.

So no bijection between the unit interval and the unit square can be continuous (in particular, cantor bijection!)

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: This does not actually answer the question as stated, since it rules out the possibility of a homeomorphism, not a continuous bijection.

This proof if a variant of User72694's answer using $\pi_1$. Suppose that we had a homeomorphism from the square interval to the square.  We will first show that their is an interior point of the interval whose image is an interior point of the square. This is easy since any bijection, $\phi$ from the interval to the square restricts to a bijection of the form, $\bar{\phi}:(0,1)\to [0,1]^2-\{\phi(0),\phi(1)\}$. So pick an interior point of $\{\phi(0),\phi(1)\}$ and it's preimage will be an interior point of the interval. Denote the interior point of the interval by $x_0$. Then the bijection $\phi$ indices a bijection, $\hat{\phi}:[0,1]-\{x_0\}\to [0,1]^2-\{\phi(x_0)\}$, which is a homeomorphism if $\phi$ is. But then $[0,1]-\{x_0\}$ is disconnected and  $[0,1]^2-\{\phi(x_0)\}$ is connected, thus their can be no homeomorphism.

Note that this is a variant of the other proof since both proofs rely on some sort of connectivity.